# Panadas rolling sum based on minutes in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df and I want to sum with rolling (and **not** with groupby)

```
       dateTime        1min       hour    minute X  EXPECTED Rolling_X
2017-09-19 02:00:04 2017-09-19 02:00:00 2   0   93  93
2017-09-19 02:00:04 2017-09-19 02:00:00 2   0   1   94
2017-09-19 02:00:04 2017-09-19 02:00:00 2   0   1   95
2017-09-19 02:00:04 2017-09-19 02:00:00 2   0   0   95
2017-09-19 02:00:04 2017-09-19 02:00:00 2   0   0   95
2017-09-19 02:00:22 2017-09-19 02:00:00 2   0   1   96
2017-09-19 02:00:22 2017-09-19 02:00:00 2   0   1   97
2017-09-19 02:00:22 2017-09-19 02:00:00 2   0   2   99
2017-09-19 02:00:58 2017-09-19 02:00:00 2   0   1   100
2017-09-19 02:00:58 2017-09-19 02:00:00 2   0   0   100
2017-09-19 02:01:00 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   7   7
2017-09-19 02:01:00 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   0   7
2017-09-19 02:01:00 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   0   7
2017-09-19 02:01:31 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   0   7
2017-09-19 02:01:31 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   1   8
2017-09-19 02:01:32 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   1   9
2017-09-19 02:01:34 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   0   9
2017-09-19 02:01:35 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   0   9
2017-09-19 02:01:35 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   0   9
2017-09-19 02:01:39 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   1   10
2017-09-19 02:01:58 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   2   12
2017-09-19 02:01:58 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   0   12
2017-09-19 02:02:02 2017-09-19 02:02:00 2   2   3   3
2017-09-19 02:02:32 2017-09-19 02:02:00 2   2   0   3
2017-09-19 02:02:32 2017-09-19 02:02:00 2   2   1   4
2017-09-19 02:02:40 2017-09-19 02:02:00 2   2   0   4
2017-09-19 02:02:41 2017-09-19 02:02:00 2   2   0   4
2017-09-19 02:02:44 2017-09-19 02:02:00 2   2   1   5
2017-09-19 02:02:53 2017-09-19 02:02:00 2   2   1   6
2017-09-19 02:03:00 2017-09-19 02:03:00 2   3   1   1
2017-09-19 02:03:00 2017-09-19 02:03:00 2   3   1   2
2017-09-19 02:03:05 2017-09-19 02:03:00 2   3   1   3
2017-09-19 02:03:06 2017-09-19 02:03:00 2   3   0   3
```

The problem is I need the rolling sum per minute so the question is:
how do I reset the rolling sum based on a change in the minutes?

```
df.X.cumsum()
```

how do I add there the reset?

thanks!
edited: something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46144380/pandas-taking-cumulative-sum-with-reset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `shift` in your the calculation for 's' from the solution mentioned in [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46144655/6361531):

```
s = df['dateTime'].dt.floor('T').diff().shift(-1).eq(pd.Timedelta('1 minute'))
s1 = df['X'].cumsum()

df['CumX'] = s.mul(s1).diff().where(lambda x: x < 0).ffill().add(s1, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
              dateTime                 1min  hour  minute   X  EXPECTED Rolling_X   CumX
0  2017-09-19 02:00:04  2017-09-19 02:00:00     2       0  93                  93   93.0
1  2017-09-19 02:00:04  2017-09-19 02:00:00     2       0   1                  94   94.0
2  2017-09-19 02:00:04  2017-09-19 02:00:00     2       0   1                  95   95.0
3  2017-09-19 02:00:04  2017-09-19 02:00:00     2       0   0                  95   95.0
4  2017-09-19 02:00:04  2017-09-19 02:00:00     2       0   0                  95   95.0
5  2017-09-19 02:00:22  2017-09-19 02:00:00     2       0   1                  96   96.0
6  2017-09-19 02:00:22  2017-09-19 02:00:00     2       0   1                  97   97.0
7  2017-09-19 02:00:22  2017-09-19 02:00:00     2       0   2                  99   99.0
8  2017-09-19 02:00:58  2017-09-19 02:00:00     2       0   1                 100  100.0
9  2017-09-19 02:00:58  2017-09-19 02:00:00     2       0   0                 100  100.0
10 2017-09-19 02:01:00  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   7                   7    7.0
11 2017-09-19 02:01:00  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   0                   7    7.0
12 2017-09-19 02:01:00  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   0                   7    7.0
13 2017-09-19 02:01:31  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   0                   7    7.0
14 2017-09-19 02:01:31  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   1                   8    8.0
15 2017-09-19 02:01:32  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   1                   9    9.0
16 2017-09-19 02:01:34  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   0                   9    9.0
17 2017-09-19 02:01:35  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   0                   9    9.0
18 2017-09-19 02:01:35  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   0                   9    9.0
19 2017-09-19 02:01:39  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   1                  10   10.0
20 2017-09-19 02:01:58  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   2                  12   12.0
21 2017-09-19 02:01:58  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   0                  12   12.0
22 2017-09-19 02:02:02  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2   3                   3    3.0
23 2017-09-19 02:02:32  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2   0                   3    3.0
24 2017-09-19 02:02:32  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2   1                   4    4.0
25 2017-09-19 02:02:40  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2   0                   4    4.0
26 2017-09-19 02:02:41  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2   0                   4    4.0
27 2017-09-19 02:02:44  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2   1                   5    5.0
28 2017-09-19 02:02:53  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2   1                   6    6.0
29 2017-09-19 02:03:00  2017-09-19 02:03:00     2       3   1                   1    1.0
30 2017-09-19 02:03:00  2017-09-19 02:03:00     2       3   1                   2    2.0
31 2017-09-19 02:03:05  2017-09-19 02:03:00     2       3   1                   3    3.0
32 2017-09-19 02:03:06  2017-09-19 02:03:00     2       3   0                   3    3.0
```

Comment: thanks. is there any way to change the '1 minute' to any larger scale?

Comment: Yes, you use '5 days' or '10 minuntes'.  Just have to look at docs on pd.Timedelta constructor.

Comment: I read the documentation here:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html and tried to run both  s = df['dateTime'].dt.floor('T').diff().shift(-1).eq(pd.Timedelta('3 minutes'))
     or s = df['dateTime'].dt.floor('T').diff().shift(-1).eq(pd.Timedelta(minutes=3)) and both failed and there is no reset. Any idea why?

Comment: Hrm.. I not not completely sure if you want to increase your floor or your reset interval.  Would you mind creating a new question with same data again and expected output?

Comment: check here pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495233/panadas-rolling-sum-based-on-multiply-minutes-in-python