# Panadas rolling sum based on MULTIPLY minutes in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df

```
   dateTime        1min       hour    minute    X   EXPECTED Rolling_X
2017-09-19 02:00:04 2017-09-19 02:00:00 2   0   93  93
2017-09-19 02:00:04 2017-09-19 02:00:00 2   0   1   94
2017-09-19 02:00:04 2017-09-19 02:00:00 2   0   1   95
2017-09-19 02:00:22 2017-09-19 02:00:00 2   0   2   97
2017-09-19 02:01:31 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   0   97
2017-09-19 02:01:31 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   1   98
2017-09-19 02:01:32 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   1   99
2017-09-19 02:01:34 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   0   99
2017-09-19 02:01:35 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   0   99
2017-09-19 02:01:35 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   0   99
2017-09-19 02:01:39 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   1   100
2017-09-19 02:01:58 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   2   102
2017-09-19 02:01:58 2017-09-19 02:01:00 2   1   0   102
2017-09-19 02:02:02 2017-09-19 02:02:00 2   2   3   3
2017-09-19 02:02:32 2017-09-19 02:02:00 2   2   0   3
2017-09-19 02:02:32 2017-09-19 02:02:00 2   2   1   4
2017-09-19 02:02:40 2017-09-19 02:02:00 2   2   15  19
2017-09-19 02:02:41 2017-09-19 02:02:00 2   2   6   25
2017-09-19 02:02:44 2017-09-19 02:02:00 2   2   1   26
2017-09-19 02:02:53 2017-09-19 02:02:00 2   2   3   29
2017-09-19 02:03:00 2017-09-19 02:03:00 2   3   1   30
2017-09-19 02:03:00 2017-09-19 02:03:00 2   3   1   31
2017-09-19 02:03:05 2017-09-19 02:03:00 2   3   1   32
2017-09-19 02:04:07 2017-09-19 02:04:00 2   4   7   7
2017-09-19 02:04:58 2017-09-19 02:04:00 2   4   2   9
2017-09-19 02:05:22 2017-09-19 02:05:00 2   5   11  20
2017-09-19 02:05:36 2017-09-19 02:05:00 2   5   11  31
```

I am looking to get the rolling sum every 2 minutes so every 2 minutes it will be reseted as in the expected column in the above df).
I am using the following code but it's not working (though it does work when I use it per 1 minute)

```
 s = df['dateTime'].dt.floor('T').diff().shift(-1).eq(pd.Timedelta('2 minutes'))
 s1 = df['X'].cumsum()
 df['2min_CumX'] = s.mul(s1).diff().where(lambda x: x < 0).ffill().add(s1, fill_value=0)
```

I read the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html) and looks like the structure is correct though it's not working as expected.

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your floor argument.

```
s = df['dateTime'].dt.floor('2T').diff().shift(-1).eq(pd.Timedelta('2 minutes'))
s1 = df['X'].cumsum()
df['2min_CumX'] = s.mul(s1).diff().where(lambda x: x < 0).ffill().add(s1, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
              dateTime                 1min  hour  minute   X  EXPECTED Rolling_X  2min_CumX
0  2017-09-19 02:00:04  2017-09-19 02:00:00     2       0  93                  93       93.0
1  2017-09-19 02:00:04  2017-09-19 02:00:00     2       0   1                  94       94.0
2  2017-09-19 02:00:04  2017-09-19 02:00:00     2       0   1                  95       95.0
3  2017-09-19 02:00:22  2017-09-19 02:00:00     2       0   2                  97       97.0
4  2017-09-19 02:01:31  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   0                  97       97.0
5  2017-09-19 02:01:31  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   1                  98       98.0
6  2017-09-19 02:01:32  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   1                  99       99.0
7  2017-09-19 02:01:34  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   0                  99       99.0
8  2017-09-19 02:01:35  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   0                  99       99.0
9  2017-09-19 02:01:35  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   0                  99       99.0
10 2017-09-19 02:01:39  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   1                 100      100.0
11 2017-09-19 02:01:58  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   2                 102      102.0
12 2017-09-19 02:01:58  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   0                 102      102.0
13 2017-09-19 02:02:02  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2   3                   3        3.0
14 2017-09-19 02:02:32  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2   0                   3        3.0
15 2017-09-19 02:02:32  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2   1                   4        4.0
16 2017-09-19 02:02:40  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2  15                  19       19.0
17 2017-09-19 02:02:41  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2   6                  25       25.0
18 2017-09-19 02:02:44  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2   1                  26       26.0
19 2017-09-19 02:02:53  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2   3                  29       29.0
20 2017-09-19 02:03:00  2017-09-19 02:03:00     2       3   1                  30       30.0
21 2017-09-19 02:03:00  2017-09-19 02:03:00     2       3   1                  31       31.0
22 2017-09-19 02:03:05  2017-09-19 02:03:00     2       3   1                  32       32.0
23 2017-09-19 02:04:07  2017-09-19 02:04:00     2       4   7                   7        7.0
24 2017-09-19 02:04:58  2017-09-19 02:04:00     2       4   2                   9        9.0
25 2017-09-19 02:05:22  2017-09-19 02:05:00     2       5  11                  20       20.0
26 2017-09-19 02:05:36  2017-09-19 02:05:00     2       5  11                  31       31.0
```

Comment: thanks. after fighting with the data I understood I made a mistake with the definition of the need. I need continues rolling sum. can you pls check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510042/continues-rolling-sum-by-multiply-minutes-of-datetime-in-python thanks