# continues rolling sum by multiply minutes of datetime in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df

```
      dateTime                  1min        hour minute X   EXPECTED Rolling_X
2017-09-19  02:00:04    2017-09-19  02:00:00    2   0   5   5
2017-09-19  02:00:04    2017-09-19  02:00:00    2   0   1   6
2017-09-19  02:00:04    2017-09-19  02:00:00    2   0   1   7
2017-09-19  02:00:22    2017-09-19  02:00:00    2   0   2   9
2017-09-19  02:01:31    2017-09-19  02:01:00    2   1   0   9
2017-09-19  02:01:31    2017-09-19  02:01:00    2   1   1   10
2017-09-19  02:01:32    2017-09-19  02:01:00    2   1   1   11
2017-09-19  02:01:34    2017-09-19  02:01:00    2   1   6   17
2017-09-19  02:01:35    2017-09-19  02:01:00    2   1   5   22
2017-09-19  02:01:35    2017-09-19  02:01:00    2   1   0   22
2017-09-19  02:01:39    2017-09-19  02:01:00    2   1   1   23
2017-09-19  02:01:58    2017-09-19  02:01:00    2   1   2   25
2017-09-19  02:01:58    2017-09-19  02:01:00    2   1   0   25
2017-09-19  02:02:02    2017-09-19  02:02:00    2   2   3   19
2017-09-19  02:02:32    2017-09-19  02:02:00    2   2   0   19
2017-09-19  02:02:32    2017-09-19  02:02:00    2   2   1   20
2017-09-19  02:02:40    2017-09-19  02:02:00    2   2   15  35
2017-09-19  02:02:41    2017-09-19  02:02:00    2   2   6   41
2017-09-19  02:02:44    2017-09-19  02:02:00    2   2   1   42
2017-09-19  02:02:53    2017-09-19  02:02:00    2   2   3   45
2017-09-19  02:03:00    2017-09-19  02:03:00    2   3   1   30
2017-09-19  02:03:00    2017-09-19  02:03:00    2   3   1   31
2017-09-19  02:03:05    2017-09-19  02:03:00    2   3   1   32
2017-09-19  02:04:07    2017-09-19  02:04:00    2   4   7   10
2017-09-19  02:04:58    2017-09-19  02:04:00    2   4   2   12
2017-09-19  02:05:22    2017-09-19  02:05:00    2   5   11  23
2017-09-19  02:05:36    2017-09-19  02:05:00    2   5   2   25
```

I am looking for **continues rolling sum** which is depended on the minutes.

I need a continues rolling for the last 2 minutes. so every time I get the sum of X but when the datetime is increasing by 1 minute than it will drop the prior tailed 1 min so alway I will have only last 2 minutes.
The problem is that there is no same amount of data per each minute.

I tried you use:

```
s2m = df['dateTime'].dt.floor('2T').diff().shift(-1).eq(pd.Timedelta('2 minutes'))
s2m1 = df['X'].cumsum()
df['truncate_2m'] = s2m.mul(s2m1).diff().where(lambda x: x < 0).ffill().add(s2m1, fill_value=0)
```

but it is resting the sum every 2 minutes and not doing continues rolling.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you need rolling now.

```
df = df.set_index('dateTime')
df['Roll_X'] = df.rolling('2T')['X'].sum()
df
```

Output:

```
                                    1min  hour  minute   X  EXPECTED Rolling_X  Roll_X
dateTime                                                                              
2017-09-19 02:00:04  2017-09-19 02:00:00     2       0   5                   5     5.0
2017-09-19 02:00:04  2017-09-19 02:00:00     2       0   1                   6     6.0
2017-09-19 02:00:04  2017-09-19 02:00:00     2       0   1                   7     7.0
2017-09-19 02:00:22  2017-09-19 02:00:00     2       0   2                   9     9.0
2017-09-19 02:01:31  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   0                   9     9.0
2017-09-19 02:01:31  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   1                  10    10.0
2017-09-19 02:01:32  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   1                  11    11.0
2017-09-19 02:01:34  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   6                  17    17.0
2017-09-19 02:01:35  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   5                  22    22.0
2017-09-19 02:01:35  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   0                  22    22.0
2017-09-19 02:01:39  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   1                  23    23.0
2017-09-19 02:01:58  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   2                  25    25.0
2017-09-19 02:01:58  2017-09-19 02:01:00     2       1   0                  25    25.0
2017-09-19 02:02:02  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2   3                  19    28.0
2017-09-19 02:02:32  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2   0                  19    19.0
2017-09-19 02:02:32  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2   1                  20    20.0
2017-09-19 02:02:40  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2  15                  35    35.0
2017-09-19 02:02:41  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2   6                  41    41.0
2017-09-19 02:02:44  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2   1                  42    42.0
2017-09-19 02:02:53  2017-09-19 02:02:00     2       2   3                  45    45.0
2017-09-19 02:03:00  2017-09-19 02:03:00     2       3   1                  30    46.0
2017-09-19 02:03:00  2017-09-19 02:03:00     2       3   1                  31    47.0
2017-09-19 02:03:05  2017-09-19 02:03:00     2       3   1                  32    48.0
2017-09-19 02:04:07  2017-09-19 02:04:00     2       4   7                  10    36.0
2017-09-19 02:04:58  2017-09-19 02:04:00     2       4   2                  12    12.0
2017-09-19 02:05:22  2017-09-19 02:05:00     2       5  11                  23    20.0
2017-09-19 02:05:36  2017-09-19 02:05:00     2       5   2                  25    22.0
```

**Check around 2:03 where values differ.**  How did you calculate 30 when I got 46?